# Developing android application in separate working modules

Tags: android

I have seen applications with add-on modules on market - these modules add-up some new functionality.
What would be the best way to do that ?

I cannot think of a descent and neat way to do that.

Comment: Good question +1 and welcome to SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways. The most common is to just install another application and access it via [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)s. It's definitely worth looking at [Open Intents](http://openintents.org). If you are really adventurous, you can even load custom plugins with [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html).

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the only way to cleanly implement this is to use Android's build-in extensibility, namely by using Intents and/or BroadcastReceivers. This is the way Android apps are supposed to communicate with each other, but it may work perfectly also for your own app by creating a main version which is extensible through Intents by your "plug-ins" which can be downloaded separately from the market.

The things you need to learn about and look for on the web to implement such functionality are

- **[Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)**: Learn how you can use intents to pass data from one app to another or to invoke certain functionality on other apps.
- **[BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)**: For listening to certain events broadcasted by your app in your "plug-ins"
- **[ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)**: The content provider is used to provide an abstraction over your data and allows your "plug-ins" to access your app data easily and nicely decoupled through Content URIs.
- **[Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)**: These are used to tell the system which kind of actions/Intents my specific Activity is able to accept. You will need them as a way for invoking your plug-ins (by broadcasting an Intent with the given action/category) as well as for providing a space in your menus where "compatible" Intents may hook in automatically.

I hope I was able to provide you some of the topics you need to know about. I'm sure that once you get a deeper understanding on these, you will get a much clearer picture on how to realize such a modular app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. both answers are same technically, though your answer is more described, I accepted the one came before.